# Function com enum - TYPESCRIPT

Tags: funções, typescript, enums

Bom preciso colocar uma função em um enum no typescript como no exemplo abaixo:

```
export enum dataTableFunc{
    'edit'= teste()
}


function teste(event.button){
//
}
```

Nessa function que estou tentando passar para o enum ainda deve receber um ou mais parametro, isso vai ser definido no momento da immplementação da function. 
E minha duvida é a seguinte, isso é possível? Se sim como posso fazer isso?
Realizei umas pesquisas na documentação mais não tive muito sucesso....

Comment: Já tentou apenas `'edit': teste`, sem os parenteses?

Comment: Já, o typescript não permite.

Comment: O `enum` é definido com `=` e não `:` ainda assim não me parece um caso para usar `enum` uma vez que isso é informação construída dinamicamente. `enum` regra geral é algo estático definido antes do programa lançar.

Comment: @Isac muito obrigado pela correção, nem tinha reparado fiz direto no editor aqui e nem me toquei. Porém em relação a estática do typescript concordo, mas no doc mostra a possibilidade de se trabalhar com classe, mas não do jeito que quero. Pensei em uma outra abordagem sem ser com enum par solucionar meu problema. Se der certo vou fechar a pergunta aqui.